# How to write a php function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

i'm trying to do this:

```
function myFunction($id, $id2) {
  $cl=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id2 FROM users WHERE id = :id");
  $cl->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $cl->execute();
  $cli=$cl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $lid=$cli['id2'];
  if($id !== $id2) {
    exit("mismatch error");
  }
}
```

then i want to call myFunction on another page.

```
myFunction($id, $id2);
```

how can i do this correctly on another page?

---

**let me explain better. here is what im trying to do.**

i have been putting this on every page:

```
$cl=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id2 FROM users WHERE id = :id");
  $cl->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $cl->execute();
  $cli=$cl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $lid=$cli['id2'];
  if($id !== $id2) {
    exit("mismatch error");
  }
}
```

but how would i make that into a function?

Comment: Include the file in that page and then call the function. be sure to use `$cl`, `$dbh` as global, otherwise you will get error of access

Comment: you have a variable scope issue http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Include the file where your function is located.

```
<?php
include 'functionFile.php';
echo myFunction($id, $id2);
?>
```

Comment: that won't work; variable scope http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: i just answered what is the question, not the problem of `variable scope`.

Comment: Funny; @deceze just closed the question about that. He's pretty spot on when it comes to stuff like this. Your answer doesn't solve it. They already declared the function and the variables. However, I'll eat my words if the OP agrees.